# Kinesis Client Library (KCL) shows "NoSuchFieldError" / "ClassNotFoundException"

Tags: amazon-kinesis

Simple KCL consumer sample code used to work.

Added few extra libraries and the following error happens:

- `java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: NOT_INTS`
- `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.cbor.CBORFactory`

Answer (score 0):

According to [this](https://github.com/awslabs/amazon-kinesis-client/issues/503) and [this](https://github.com/awslabs/amazon-kinesis-client/issues/200), this is caused by mismatching `jackson` versions. Most probably because a new library with a breaking `jackson` version dependeny is introduced.

Check:

- Whether you have included AWS SDK as a dependency - this is not needed as KCL will find its own dependency
- Whether you are mixing different AWS SDK / KCL versions (both have v1 and v2)

Use `mvn dependency:tree` to check dependency.